# PHP crashes using isset function

Tags: php, arrays, crash, isset

I've got a problem with my code. I used to have "Undefinied offset:1" error so I'm using isset function to check if the array exists. But after submitting, the web server crashes (I got the problem because of this for sure)

PHP Code

```php
if ($instancenameNarr !== null && $instancenameVarr !== null && $instancenameOarr !== null) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $input['standardpartitionsN']; $i++) {
                $standardpartitions = new StandardPartition;

if (isset($input['mounpointstandardpartitionsN'][$i])) {
    $standardpartitions->mountpointstd = $input['mounpointstandardpartitionsN'][$i--];

}

if (isset($input['sizestandardpartitionsN'][$i])) {
    $standardpartitions->sizestd = $input['sizestandardpartitionsN'][$i--];
}

                $standardpartitions->save();
```

HTML

```html
<select class="form-control"  name='mounpointstandardpartitionsN[]'  id='mounpointstandardpartitionsN' >
```

and so on... What is the problem guys? Thank you

Comment: You probably don't need the `$i--` in the various places.  What did you expect them to do for you?

Comment: I changed them to : $i-1 as @Gabriel Souto said. But i have now Undefined offset: -1 again

Comment: My point is - do you need it at all - should it just be `$i`.  But I'm not sure why you want to look at the previous item so I can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you set $i-- your 'for' goes one step back, and loops forever. Try $i - 1 but testing again if it's exists

```
if (isset($input['mounpointstandardpartitionsN'][$i])) {
 if (isset($input['mounpointstandardpartitionsN'][$i - 1])) {
    $standardpartitions->mountpointstd = $input['mounpointstandardpartitionsN'][$i - 1];
 }
}
```

And you have to check if its the first iteration too

Comment: Okay, now server don't crashes but I have again "Undefined offset: -1"

Answer (score 0):

You should first check `mounpointstandardpartitionsN` and then check `$i` as below:

```
<?php 
if ($instancenameNarr !== null && $instancenameVarr !== null && $instancenameOarr !== null) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $input['standardpartitionsN']; $i++) {
        $standardpartitions = new StandardPartition;

if (isset($input['mounpointstandardpartitionsN']) && isset($input['mounpointstandardpartitionsN'][$i])) {
    $standardpartitions->mountpointstd = $input['mounpointstandardpartitionsN'][$i--];
}

if (isset($input['sizestandardpartitionsN']) && isset($input['sizestandardpartitionsN'][$i])) {
    $standardpartitions->sizestd = $input['sizestandardpartitionsN'][$i--];
}

$standardpartitions->save();
```

This will firstly check if `$input` has `mounpointstandardpartitionsN` set and if yes, then it will check if `$input['mounpointstandardpartitionsN']` has `$i` in it. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Solved by applying

```
count($input[...][$i])
```

and so on. Count() saved me